# Deleting a row from a csv(Python)

Tags: python

So, I'm trying to make a function to delete a row from my csv depending on the Name given by the parameter.

Original File:

```
Janet,5,cats
Wilson,67,dogs
Karen,8,mice
John,12,birds
```

My Code:

```
csv_remove("Karen")
```

Intended File:

```
Janet,5,cats
Wilson,67,dogs
John,12,birds
```

However, when I execute my code, I get weird newlines everywhere.

```
Janet,5,cats

Wilson,67,dogs

John,12,birds
```

Here is the full code:

```
def csv_remove(name):
    element_list = []
    with open(csv_path, 'r') as j:
        csv_file = csv.reader(j)
        for row in csv_file:
            element_list.append(row)
            if row[0] == name:
                element_list.remove(row)
    with open(csv_path, 'w') as j:
        csv_file = csv.writer(j)
        csv_file.writerows(element_list)

csv_remove("Karen")
```

Answer (score 3):

Read the documentation. When opening a file for writing using the csv-module you need to
supply `newline=""`:

Source:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer

> csv.**writer**(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)
> Return a writer object responsible for converting the user’s data into delimited strings on the given file-like object. csvfile can be any object with a write() method. If csvfile is a file object, **it should be opened with newline=''**

The csv-module handles newlines itself. If you do not specify `newline=''` for the opened file, it will muck up the line endings and you end up with empty lines in it.